# React doesn't change input value with looping array for initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

How can i update a value for input text in a state array? Here is the code that I am currently using:

> This is for initial state react hooks

```
const [kernelSize, setKernelSize] = useState(3)
const [kernel, setKernel] = useState([])
```

> Input range for size of kernel

<input type="range" step="2" name="range" min="3" max="7" value={kernelSize} className="slider" onChange={(e) => handleKernel(e)} />

> This is for handleKernel function

```
const handleKernel = (e) => {
    setKernelSize(e.target.value)
    let kernel = []
    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.value; i++) {
        kernel.push([])
        for (let j = 0; j < e.target.value; j++) {
            kernel[i].push(1)
        }
    }
    setKernel(kernel)
}
```

> This is for looping input text based size/length from input range

```
{
kernel.map((value, index) => {
    return (
        <div className="row mt-3" key={`${index}_${value}`}>
            {
                value.map((value_2, index_2) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="input-wrap" key={`${index_2}_${value_2}`}>
                            <input type="text" id="" className="form-control" value={value_2} onChange={(e) => updateKernel(e, index, index_2)} />
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
})}
```

> This is for updateKernel function

```
const updateKernel = (e, index, index_2) => () => {
    let kernelCopy = [...kernel];
    kernelCopy[index][index_2] = e.target.value;
    setKernel(kernelCopy);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue here is that you aren't also shallow copying the nested inner array that is being updated.

```
const updateKernel = (e, index, index_2) => {
  // use a functional state update to update from previous state
  setKernel((kernel) =>
    // shallow copy outer array
    kernel.map((outerEl, i1) =>
      i1 === index
        // shallow copy inner array on index match
        ? outerEl.map((innerEl, i2) =>
            // update at index match or return current
            i2 === index_2 ? e.target.value : innerEl 
          )
        : outerEl
    )
  );
};
```

### Update

Inputs lose focus because of the way you've defined the React keys. The keys use the index and current value, both of which are probably the two worst values you could choose for React keys. The issue is that upon each change the key is now a different value and React unmounts the previous input and mounts a new one.

The solution is to use stable keys that persist and live for the ***entire*** life of the data it's representing in React. For this I suggest using objects with an `id` property for the key, and a `value` property for the value being rendered.

Here's a full code example using the [uuid package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to generate GUIds.

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid";

function App() {
  const [kernelSize, setKernelSize] = useState(3);
  const [kernel, setKernel] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let kernel = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < kernelSize; i++) {
      kernel.push({
        id: uuidV4(), // <-- generate a row id
        value: []
      });
      for (let j = 0; j < kernelSize; j++) {
        kernel[i].value.push({
          id: uuidV4(), // <-- generate element id
          value: 1
        });
      }
    }
    setKernel(kernel);
  }, [kernelSize]);

  const handleKernel = (e) => {
    setKernelSize(e.target.value);
  };

  const updateKernel = (index, index2) => (e) => {
    setKernel((kernel) =>
      kernel.map((outerEl, i1) =>
        i1 === index
          ? {
              ...outerEl,
              value: outerEl.value.map((innerEl, i2) =>
                i2 === index2
                  ? {
                      ...innerEl,
                      value: e.target.value
                    }
                  : innerEl
              )
            }
          : outerEl
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="range"
        step="2"
        name="range"
        min="3"
        max="7"
        value={kernelSize}
        className="slider"
        onChange={handleKernel}
      />

      <div>
        {kernel.map((row, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="row mt-3" key={row.id}> // <-- use id as React key
              {row.value.map(({ id, value }, index_2) => {
                return (
                  <span className="input-wrap" key={id}> // <-- use id as React key
                    <input
                      style={{
                        width: "2rem"
                      }}
                      type="text"
                      id=""
                      className="form-control"
                      value={value}
                      onChange={updateKernel(index, index_2)}
                    />
                  </span>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-doesnt-change-input-value-with-looping-array-for-initial-value]

Comment: Hmm still doesn't work with me :(
Is because i map through kernel state and, kernel state are change from input range? Not only from input text?

Comment: @MMuqiitFaturrahman Oh, sorry, had a typo in the body, I had `index2` instead of `index_2`. I updated to match the passed argument, please check it again. Otherwise I'm working on creating a running codesandbox if there's further issue. Can you add all the relevant component code to your question? Out of curiosity, are you creating a convolution filter?

Comment: I tried the same code in codesandbox but the issue is after one character is updated the state is set a new and all the components are recreated with the updated value and the one that was being edited looses it's focus, I think this could be fixed using refs?

Comment: @sathyareddy I see the very same here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-doesnt-change-input-value-with-looping-array-for-initial-value-9prlj?file=/src/App.js). Looking into it now.

Comment: @sathyareddy Inputs were losing focus because of poor React keys. I updated my answer to include this issue and a possible solution. Please do check it. Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry the is a typo in my code, thank you for your help!

Comment: @DrewReese yes i'm curently create a convolution filter by using opencv.js for react. This is really interesting, but tutorial of opencv.js is so hard to find. Ideally, i can go from react to flask/django but i don't really "well" for that framework, i just comfortable with react js.